# How to remove all the duplicated words on every line using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, duplicate

I'm working on a file containing lines with keywords and some lines contain duplicated keywords.

For example:

```
dangerous,dangerous,hazardous,perilous
```

I want to tell Notepad++ that I want to remove every duplicated word per line. For this example `dangerous,` would be removed:

```
dangerous,hazardous,perilous
```

I have a bunch of lines like that and that's why I'm looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: What about `dangerous,hazardous,dangerous,perilous`? In other words, are duplicated words always next to each other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove consecutive duplicated words in a line, however I don't think it's possible to remove duplicated words which are not consecutive (e.g `dangerous, hazardous, dangerous`).

### **Use this regex in the replace window in Notepad++, and don't forget to select "Regular expression" as the Search Mode option below:**

**This regex will remove all consecutive duplicated words - whether it's 2 duplicated words or 10 duplicated words consecutively:** `\b(\w+)(?:,\s+\1\b)+`.

The exact same no-commas regex would be: `\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1\b)+` (might be useful for other users).

If you want a regex specifically for only two duplicated words (doubles), use this regex: `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1`.

**Place this regex in the *Replace with* box to keep one occurrence of the word (otherwise all repeated words will be removed):** `${1}`.

These regular expressions will fix a situation like the one you described in your question as an example. The first regex will work for every number of duplicated words (e.g `dangerous, dangerous, dangerous, dangerous, hazardous`), while the second version will only work for two duplicated words (e.g `dangerous, dangerous, hazardous`).

**Note:** The regular expression will only apply to the format described in the question, meaning that formats like `two words, two words, anotherword`, `two-words, two-words, anotherword`, `three words expression, three words expression, anotherword` won't be changed because the regex won't apply to them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I'm getting 0 occurrences, I tried doing this with separated keywords as you suggested and it didn't work, I also tried as they were before and nothing, please check my screen capture: http://goo.gl/eZ7Kp

Comment: This regex should work: `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1` for two duplicated words. I'll edit my answer. The commas are why the other regex doesn't work.

Comment: I tried every possible combination, no commas, only spaces, no space and comma, and yet nothing. Please enlight me, here's the text file: http://goo.gl/sP20z

Comment: The problem is that the regular expression I wrote in my answer only applies to the format (I thought) you asked for: `word, word, anotherword`. However, you have many instances which are a little bit different, like `came across, came across` and some with 3 or 4 words. Also there are words with `'` like `don't` and it makes things more complicated in the *Notepad++ regex system*. The Notepad++ regex system is pretty annoying and limited as well, so the solution is to either use regex in python (or another language), or make format-specific regular expressions for the Notepad++.

Comment: Another problem is that most of the words that are duplicated also appear in the previous line, which makes it difficult to achieve your goal. If you'd want to remove *all* duplicated words, then it wasn't that difficult. You could do something like [this](http://www.mind-pioneer.com/services/913_Regular_expression_replace.html) & [this](http://www.mind-pioneer.com/services/172_Advanced_search_and_replace.html). I suggest you use specific regular expressions in Notepad++ (I can help you, just tell me all the formats of the duplicated words) or consider a different approach to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do the job, this will replace all duplicate words even if they are not contiguous:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)(\b\w+\b),?(?=.*\1)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)    : non capture group, beginning of line or position of last match
(\b\w+\b)   : group 1, 1 or more word character (ie. [a-zA-Z0-9_]), surrounded by word boundaries
,?          : optional comma
(?=.*\1)    : positive lookahead, check if thhere is the same word (contained in group 1) somewhere after
```

Given an input like:
   `dangerous,dangerous,hazardous,perilous,dangerous,dangerous,hazardous,perilous`

We got:

```
dangerous,hazardous,perilous
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Really helpful. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>